# What do dots after "Resolving dependencies" from bundle install (or bundle update) mean?

Tags: ruby, bundler

Every time I run `bundle install` or `bundle update`, Ruby Bundler outputs something like this:

```
Resolving dependencies....................
```

The dots come out at a variable speed, sometimes tens of them in a second, sometimes stuck for a few seconds.

Just now I ran `bundle update` in my Jekyll blog and Bundler generated over 5,000 dots and I had to Ctrl-C it.

What do these dots mean?

Comment: If it never finishes you may have gotten into a state where there is no way to satisfy all of the version constraints. You can try removing the `.lock` file and starting over, roll back to a known working state, or remove dependencies until it works, then add them back in one by one until it fails to find out which one is breaking it.

Answer (score 4):

Each gem you specify will have a list of dependent gems that it requires to run, and each of these dependencies will have a minimum and maximum compatible version.

When bundle is resolving dependencies, it's first of all ensuring the gemset you're requesting is even possible (i.e. there isn't one gem requiring ActionPack < 4 and another requiring ActionPack > 5).

After it determines whether there is a set of gems that satisfies every requirement, it starts downloading as needed. I'm guessing it picks the latest version that satisfies every relevant dependency present.

Comment: Is there some kind of correspondence between the dots and the gems? Like one dependency resolved = one dot output?